# IE-11 Compatibility with Framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a **ASP.NET** web application. Recently we have upgraded the Framework from 2.0 to 4.5. This upgrading has forced us to use IE11. In order to make our application **IE11** compatible we have added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7;IE=EmulateIE8; IE=EmulateIE9; IE=EDGE" />
```

in the master page and also included the below tag in config file as well.

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
```

In spite of adding the above line of code the application still fails to load properly in IE11. The first page, that is, the SignIn page fails to load completely and displays a blank page. It works fine only on adding the URL of the site using Compatibility View. It is required to make this compatible to IE11 as it is not expected of the clients to set the Compatibility View every time someone plans on using the site. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you are looking for but maybe this will help and point you in the right direction. We use this for an application at work that was originally an ie6 app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Jamie, I have already implemented this but it is of no help. I have also done the IIS level settings. Still no help..

Comment: Sorry I thought you were trying to get your site to work in ie10 or below. The X-UA-Compatible does not work in ie11+ so it really doesn't do anything. Look here for the flow chat on how IE determines what to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346917/why-use-x-ua-compatible-ie-edge-anymore do you have the <!DOCTYPE> declaration?