# Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer

I am trying to figure out why my angular 2 app is stuck on showing Loading... when running in IE 11.

Following someone's suggestion, I've tried this plunker, posted by someone on stack overflow, on both chrome and IE 11.  Works fine on Chrome, but fails on IE 11.  Same error, stuck on saying "Loading..."

The plunker is : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/6zVFbrH5yohwc714gBbk?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <title>Router Sample</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'src': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('src/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Anybody got any idea as to why IE 11 fails to run the angular 2 app?

Thank you!

Comment: Answer is to use 2.0.0-beta.0 for now.

Answer (score 190):

The latest version of [`angular`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339879/what-to-do-about-angular-2)  is only setup for evergreen browsers by default...

> The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera), Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile. 
> *This also includes firefox, although not mentioned.*

*See here for more information on browser support along with a list of suggested polyfills for specific browsers. https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#polyfill-libs*

---

This means that you **manually** have to enable the correct polyfills to get Angular working in IE11 and below.

---

To achieve this, go into `polyfills.ts` (in the `src` folder by default) and just **uncomment** the following imports:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Note that the comment is literally in the file, so this is easy to find.

If you are still having issues, you can downgrade the `target` property to `es5` in `tsconfig.json` as [`@MikeDub`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429364/3509591) suggested. What this does is change the compilation output of any `es6` definitions to `es5` definitions. For example, fat arrow functions (`()=>{}`) will be compiled to anonymous functions (`function(){}`). You can find a list of es6 supported browsers [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

---

### Notes

• I was asked in the comments by `@jackOfAll` whether IE11 polyfills are loaded even if the user is in an evergreen browser which doesn't need them. The answer is, yes they are! The inclusion of the IE11 polyfills will take your polyfill file from `~162KB` to `~258KB` as of Aug 8 '17. I have invested in trying to solve this however it does not seem possible at this time.

• If you are getting errors in IE10 and below, go into you `package.json` and downgrade `webpack-dev-server` to `2.7.1` specifically. Versions higher than this no longer support "older" IE versions.

Comment: My angular 5 project also has the same error even I have uncommented the polyfill for IE, still cannot work in IE browser. Too strange....

Comment: Uncomment all the imports mentioned as well as import NgClass below that. Finally install " npm install --save classlist.js " . This worked in my case.

Comment: Re: notes
Well, yeah. Polyfills are added code to a project when trying to support the potential of a browser that doesn't support a specific functionality. You're not going to have that polyfill code magically disappear from your package when downloading the bundle via chrome; the application bundle is the application bundle is the application bundle.

Comment: @dudewad I was experimenting with creating 2 separate bundles, one explicitly for IE11, and then wrapping that bundle in an IE conditional comment which would've stopped it coming through in chrome.

Comment: @Zze well, that's certainly thorough of you. Nice, I like that.

Comment: @Zze conditional comments were removed in IE10, they're only supported in IE5-9.

So your IE bundle wouldn't be loaded for IE10+, unless you specifically did some user agent sniffing to add your bundle to the page at runtime.

Comment: @bmcminn hence the past tense ;)

Comment: You can segregate IE polyfills so they don't load in other browsers as described here: https://izifortune.com/angular-polyfill-strategies/

Comment: so i don't need to look for it in version 7? it's my nth time searching for this, and no one said a word :|

Comment: these imports are not present in my polyfill.js. if i add these imports to the polyfill.js file, it throws error. Please mention all commands i need to add for this.

Comment: I think it's worth adding that when using `target: "es5"` you still may need some additional polyfills (e.g. array.includes). Importing `import 'core-js/shim'` will fix that.
Also for fixing CSS on IE there is a file `browserslist`.

Comment: this fix working for normal build `ng build` but in prod build not working `ng build --prod`

Comment: After Migrated to Angular8+ or 9 or 10, core-js/es6 or core-js/es7 Will not work.

You have to simply replace import core-js/es/

Answer (score 23):

I had the exact same issue and none of the solutions worked for me. Instead adding the following line in the (homepage).html under `<head>` fixed it.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Considering information from this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346917/why-use-x-ua-compatible-ie-edge-anymore, recommendation to use X-UA-Compatible seems to be invalid.

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this issue today.  I found an solution on GitHub that does not require going to a later version of the beta.

Add the following script to your html:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

This resolved the problem for me.  For more details, you can follow the github issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144

Comment: this solution didn't work for me :( ... [on VS2015 project running on IE]

Answer (score 12):

**As of Feb 2017**

Using an **Angular-Cli** project, all lines in the `polyfills.ts` file were already uncommented so all polyfills were already being utilised.

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912921/ie11-issue-angular-cli-project-in-angular2ts-polyfills-are-notworking) to fix my issue.

To summarize the above link, *IE doesn't support lambda arrow / fat arrow functions* which are a feature of **es6**. (*This is if polyfills.ts doesn't work for you*).

**Solution**: you need to target **es5** for it to run in any IE versions, support for this was only introduced in the new Edge Browser by Microsoft.

This is found under `src/tsconfig.json`:

```
"outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
```

Comment: This answer is very missleading. The polyfills are the scripts which make IE 9 and above compatible with ES6 standards as seen here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html So it doesn't matter if the browser natively supports arrow functions, the polyfills mitigates this issue entirely.

Comment: How is what I experienced in my case...misleading? The polyfills were already uncommented and they did not fix the issue that I was experiencing in IE11. Hardly think this is worthy of a downvote.

Comment: After re-reading this, I understand what you are trying to say, but the way in which it is currently worded, it sounds like you have to manually change all of your `.ts` files from using fat arrow to anon funcs. I think that you should snip a quote out of that link about how the compiler output is different if you change the ecma script target which henceforth mitigates the issue.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm already targetting es5 in my tsconfig and I still have issues.

Comment: @MikeDub I tried using your solution but it is not working for IE11. Can you provide me better approach.

Answer (score 11):

> You'll need to adjust the polyfills.ts file for your target browsers
>   by uncommenting the appropriate sections.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

For me with iexplorer 11 and Angular 2 I fixed all those above issues by doing 2 things:

**in index.html**
add:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

**in src\polyfills.ts**
uncomment:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: Yes this is working for IE11 but not for IE10: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'setPrototypeOf' at EmptyError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:102653:9)`

Answer (score 10):

1. Un-comment some imports in the polyfill.ts file.

```js
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Install npm Pacakages
Notice there are some npm install commands in the comments. If you are using an early version of Angular CLI, there may also be a third one. For Angular CLI versions 7, 6, and 1.7 you need to run:

npm install --save classlist.js

npm install --save web-animations-js

now open IE and render your application and check :)

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT 2018/05/15**: This can be achieved with a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777695/410342); please add that tag to your index.html and disregard this post.

This is not a complete answer to the question (for the technical answer please refer to [@Zze's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426495/410342)), but there's an important step that **needs** to be added:

**COMPATIBILITY MODE**

Even with the appropriate polyfills in place, there are still issues with running Angular 2+ apps using the polyfills on IE11. If you are running the site off an intranet host (ie. if you are testing it at http://localhost or another mapped local domain name), you must go into Compatibility View settings and uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View", since IE11's Compatibility View breaks a couple of the conventions included in the ES5 polyfills for Angular.

[image]

Comment: If you follow this solution you have to do this on all the client running your application. Adding a special tag to your html file forces the browser to run in the latest version available instead of compatibility mode.
Refer to the following answer to find the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47777695/4628364

Comment: In my experience, if your app is served on an intranet host, the use of this meta tag does not override IE 11's default setting to 'Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View`. Users of the intranet app will still need to go in and manually uncheck this option which is less than ideal. I'm currently looking for a workaround - perhaps compiling to ES5 rather than ES6.

Answer (score 8):

As of September 2017 (node version=v6.11.3, npm version=3.10.10), this is what worked for me (thanks @Zze):

Edit `polyfills.ts` and uncomment the imports that are necessary for IE11.

More preciselly, edit `polyfills.ts` (located in the `src` folder by default) and just uncomment all lines required for IE11 (the comments inside the file explain exactly what imports are necessary to run on IE11).

A small warning: pay attention when uncommenting the lines for `classlist.js` and `web-animations-js`. These commented lines have a specific comment each: you must run the associated npm commands before uncommenting them or processing of polyfills.ts will break.

As a word of explanation, the polyfills are pieces of code that implement a feature on a web browser that do not support it.
This is why in the default polyfills.ts configuration only a minimal set of imports is active
(because it's aiming the *so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that automatically update themselves*).

Answer (score 6):

I have an Angular4 application, even for me also it was not working in IE11 browser, i have done below changes, now its working correctly.
Just add below code in the **index.html** file

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Just you need to uncomment these below lines from **polyfills.ts** file

```
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

These above 2 steps will solve your problem, please let me know if anything will be there. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have already thses 2 parts uncommented but it is still not working, do you have another solution

Answer (score 5):

If you have still problems that not all JavaScript functions are working add this line in your polyfills. It fixes the missing ‘values’ method:

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

And this line fixes the missing ‘includes’ method:

```
import 'core-js/es7/array'
```

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue, if you have enabled Display intranet sites in Compatibility View the polyfills.ts won't work, you still need to add the following line as has been told.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 3):

changing `tsconfig.json`

```
"target":"es5",
```

solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is I followed the following steps to improve my application perfomance in IE 11
1.) In Index.html file, add the following CDN's

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0- 
 beta.17/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classlist/1.2.201711092/classList.min.js"></script>
```

2.) In polyfills.ts file and add the following import:

```
import 'core-js/client/shim';
```

Answer (score 2):

> **In polyfills.ts**

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';

import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';

import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/animation`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

Answer (score 2):

If none of the other solutions work for you, it's worth investigating the source of the problem. It may be than an npm module directly inserts ES6 code, which cannot be transpiled.

In my case I had the

*SCRIPT1002: Syntax error vendor.js (114536,27)* at the following line:

```
const ucs2encode = array => String.fromCodePoint(...array);
```

I searched the *node_modules* folder and found from which file the line came. It turned out that the culprit was [punycode.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js) which in it's 2.1.0 version uses ES6 directly.

After I downgraded it to 1.4.1, which uses ES5, the problem was solved.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. While it didn't solve the problem, it though helped me to find the troublemaker module and inform it's author about the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

**How to resolve this problem in Angular8**

polyfills.ts uncomment `import 'classlist.js';`  and `import 'web-animations-js';` then install two dependency using `npm install --save classlist.js` and `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

update `tsconfig.json` with `"target":"es5",`

then `ng serve` run the application and open in IE, it will work

Answer (score 1):

1. Uncomment IE section in the src/polyfill.js,

   /** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements*/

   import 'classlist.js';
2. If any build error for missing package then,

   npm install classlist.js --save-exact
3. Make sure to include below line to set the default IE document mode. Other wise it will open in version 7

```html
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Un-comment plyfills in polyfills.ts. Also run all npm install commands mentioned in in polyfills.ts file to install those packages

Step 2: In browserslist file remove not before the line where IE 9-11 support is mentioned

Step 3: In tsconfig.json file change like "target": "es2015" to "target": "es5"

These steps fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution in this thread as well as bunch from other ones, with no success. What ended up fixing this for me was to update every package in my project, including MAJOR version changes. So:

1. Run npm outdated
2. Update package.json with the number shown in the current column from results (this can break your project, be careful)
3. Run npm install
4. Made sure I also had the polyfills uncommented as noted in the other answers.

That's it. I wish I could pinpoint which library was the culprit. The actual error I was getting was "Syntax Error" in vendor.js in Angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 9 out of the box should work absolutely fine in IE11 now.

I tried all of the suggestions listed here and none of them worked. However I did manage to track it down to a specific library I was importing in `app.module` (`ZXingScannerModule` to be precise). If your app is failing in IE11 on the first page, try removing libraries one at a time and check in IE11 - it was completely missed in all my build warning errors. If you do find this is the case, then consider compartmentalising the area of your site which uses this library as a lazy loaded module.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of core-js lib provides the polyfills from a different path. so use the following in the polyfills.js. And also change the `target` value to `es5` in the `tsconfig.base.json`

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
```