# IE11 issue Angular CLI project in Angular2(TS), polyfills are notworking

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, es5-shim

I am using anugular-cli 1.0.0-beta.16 which has polyfills.ts which looks like this:

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular 2 and is loaded before
// the app. You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

But this pollyfills file is not working on IE11 and it works on Chrome, Firefox, EDGE and my main.ts looks like this:

```
import "./polyfills.ts";
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
import {environment} from "./environments/environment";
import {AppModule} from "./app/";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Running this on IE11 produces shows error on fat arrow expression error

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

For minifiedjs at this position:

```
function arrayUnion(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1
        .concat(arr2.filter(v => arr1.indexOf(v) === -1));
}
```

and this is how my tsconfig.json looks like

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

@Cleton this is how my tsconfig looks like

Comment: Could you show your tsconfig file?

Comment: `{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
`  @Cleiton this is how my tsconfig file looks like

Comment: You tsconfig looks ok, but it is on root of your project?

Comment: Cleiton thanks  for taking efforts , this is an angular-cli project and it puts tsconfig.json in src folder where files like  1.index.html 2.main.ts 3.polyfills.ts  4.typings.d.ts resides

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably targeting `es6`, which compiles the arrow functions to arrow functions:

```
let fn = () => console.log("hey");
```

Compiles to:

```
let fn = () => console.log("hey");
```

But if you target `es5` it compiles to:

```
var fn = function () { return console.log("hey"); };
```

It seems that `IE11` (or any other version of explorer) [do not yet support arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).
If you want to support it you'll have to target `es5` or below, as there is no pollyfil for arrow functions.