# angular 2 app fails to launch on internet explorer

Tags: angular, browser

I have successfully deployed my angular 2 app.

Users reach the app through
https://www.polsannet.com/webapp/

However IE users repeatedly report that they cannot view the login page.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1:
After adding the mentioned scripts the app now routes to pagenotfound component. Again only on IE. 
UPDATE 2:
Works fine with IE on http://localhost:4200  , when deployed to prod. IE still does not launch.

polyfills.ts

```
// This file includes polyfills needed by Angular 2 and is loaded before
// the app. You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Comment: did you configurated a polyfill file?

Comment: [POLYFILL as in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-with-ie-11-not-working)

Comment: Maybe you can still add the following script to your html:

<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You should add shims for IE browser to your index.html file.

For me (app in version 2.4.0) helped these scripts:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

Insert them into *head* tag in your main html. I guess it will help even with IEv9

Comment: https://www.polsannet.com/webapp/  now it started routing to page not found component. Again only on IE. Chrome, Opera,Firefox,Edge,Safari all OK.

Comment: I guess that its a another bug. Could you create new issue for this bug and there show console errors?

Comment: @desperado06 dude, you added scripts to body tag. Read full answer.

Comment: Please help. Customers are frustrated.

Comment: I can't open your app on any browser. Without console logs I can't do anything.

Comment: OK.It's fine now. Please create new issue about unexpected routing on IE browser, and link in comment. Add to issue index.html and routing.ts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591225/angular-2-unexpected-routing-on-internet-explorer