# angular 2 unexpected routing on Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, typescript, spring-boot, angular2-routing

My spring-boot/angular 2 app(hosted on embedded tomcat) works fine on Chrome,Safari,Opera and Edge.
However on IE the app directly routes to PageNotFound component.
Added shims for IE to index.html but still no luck.
thank you in advance

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title> </title>
  <base href=".">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./res/images/favicon.ico">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- application css -->
  <link href="./res/styles/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js" async></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Uygulama Yükleniyor...</app-root>

</body>


</html>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
rt {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {OrtakListComponent} from './ortak/ortak-list.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from './page-not-found.component';
import {AuthGuard} from './guards/auth.guard';
import {ForgotPasswordComponent} from './login/forgot-password.component';
const routes:Routes =[

{path:'' , pathMatch:'full' , redirectTo:'login',},
{path:'ortak/:id', component:OrtakListComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],loadChildren:'./ortak/ortak.module#OrtakModule'},
{path:'login' , component:LoginComponent},
{path:'forgotpassword',component:ForgotPasswordComponent},
{path:'**',pathMatch:'full',component:PageNotFoundComponent},

];

@NgModule({
imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports:[RouterModule]

})

export class AppRoutingModule{}

export const routableComponents = [


    LoginComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,

];
```

Comment: https://www.polsannet.com/webapp/login is the URL

Comment: {path:'' , pathMatch:'full' , redirectTo:'login',}, change to {path:'' , pathMatch:'full' , redirectTo:'login'}, 
maybe it's problem with parsing JSON

Comment: BTW. why you don't use <base href="/"> in index.html?

Comment: tried both . still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE are you using. It will not work unless your browser supports History pushState.

Comment: thanks for ur response,IE 11, we have no problem in the test env (node server) , when deployed to prod (embedded tomcat ) app routes to pagenotfound.