# Why on Angular 2 app page reload in IE I get multiple ..js.map files not found 404 errors?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms

Ihave a Angular2 app that when I reload a page I get the following 404s..

[image]

I do not see these errors when debugging in Chrome - only IE11 an Edge (not tested on earlier IE versions or Safari etc)

I use WebPack for building.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just enter this url `http://localhost:3000/Observable.js.map//`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that most of your errors come from Observable and Subscription, it could be a compatibility problem due to ES6 expression.
[Angular 2 / 4 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-not-working-in-ie11)

Try to enable ES5 for IE instead ;)