# Angular 4 IE issue

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I built one Angular 4 application using angular/cli and deployed on XAMPP. However, on all the browsers, it works fine except for IE. When I open it in IE, I don't know but somehow the IE version changes to IE 7 (default) instead of IE 11 (default). When I change it to IE11, the application works perfectly.

I have uncommented all the 'polyfills' in 'polyfills.ts' file and installed 'classlist.js' and 'web-animation-js' as well.

Has anyone else faced this issue ?

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42426495/1608841 refer this

Comment: Have you declared doctype HTML at the beginning of your HTML base template?

Comment: thank you guys for your time. I was able to solve this issue. There is 'Compatibility View Settings' enabled where the checkbox was checked to 'display intranet sites in compatibility mode', hence the IE version changed from 11 to 7 on loading the app which is hosted on the office network.

Unchecked it, and it's working fine now.