# IE 11 angular material checkboxes display on the same place

Tags: angular, html, css

When I use angular materials checkboxes like below and display view on the Internet Explorer 11 browser it displays all checkboxes on the same place instead of side by side horizontal. How can I fix that?

[image: all checkboxes on the same place]

This is part of html code:

```
        <div class="column-container">
          <div class="column" *ngFor="let nd of filteredNetworks">
            <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="nd.Checked">
              {{nd.NetworkName}}
            </md-checkbox>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: do you set DOCTYPE for your html?

Comment: read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: Yes, of course I use DOCTYPE, this is only the part of html code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include polyfills for IE support. Open `polyfills.ts` in your application and uncomment the polyfills required (Comment is present in file showing which all are required for IE).

Comment: Have you tried running `ng serve` manually as a change in `polyfill.ts` won't initiate hot replacement

Comment: Yes, I've been used ng-serve but it still the same problem.

Comment: which version of angular material are you using ?

Comment: Version of angular material is 2.0.0-beta