# Angular 6 app not working in IE < 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

My Angular App is not working in IE lower than 11, however previously it was not even working in IE 11, but after uncommenting some imports in polyfills.ts it worked, but the problem still persists in lower versions.

Here's my polyfills.ts, package.json, and  browser console error respectively

polyfills.ts

```
/**
* This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the 
app.
You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.

This file is divided into 2 sections:
1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted 
 by browsers.
2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded 
before your main file.
*
* The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions 
of 
browsers that
automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 
(including Opera),
Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
*
* Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
/**************
BROWSER POLYFILLS
/

/* IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. */
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';


/* IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements /
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/* IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. /
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/* Evergreen browsers require these. */
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular 
decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect'; 


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web- 
animation
*/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.   



/*************************************
 * Zone JS is required by Angular itself.
/
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

import 'hammerjs/hammer';


/***********************************************************************
APPLICATION IMPORTS
/

/**
* Date, currency, decimal and percent pipes.
Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and Safari 10
/
// import 'intl';  // Run `npm install --save intl`.
/**
* Need to import at least one locale-data with intl.
*/
// import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
import 'es5-shim';
// (window as any).global = window ;
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "material",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "start-proxy": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e"
} ,
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/core": "0.6.3",
  "@angular/animations": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/common": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/core": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
  "@angular/forms": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/http": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/router": "6.0.3",
  "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
  "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.5",
  "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^2.0.12",
  "angular-calendar": "^0.22.1",
  "aws-sdk": "^2.266.1",
  "chartist": "^0.11.0",
  "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "d3": "^4.8.0",
  "es5-shim": "^4.5.10",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "intl": "^1.2.5",
  "jquery": "^3.2.1",
  "moment": "^2.20.0",
  "ng-chartist": "1.1.1",
  "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
  "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
  "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
  "ng2-smart-table": "1.2.2",
  "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
  "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.0",
  "ngx-quill": "^3.1.0",
  "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
  "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
  "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.4",
  "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "6.0.5",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.3",
  "@angular/language-service": "6.0.3",
  "@types/chartist": "^0.9.37",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
  "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5",
  "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
  "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
  "karma": "~1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
  "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
  "protractor": "~5.1.2",
  "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
  "tslint": "~5.7.0",
  "typescript": "2.7.2",
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3"
  }
  }
```

console Error in IE 10
[image]

and for IE 9 console is empty.

Please suggest a possible solution.

Comment: read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/) help

Comment: @MohammadDaliri In IE 11 it's working , concern is about lower versions

Comment: What worked for me is making some changes in the tsconfig.json file. Make sure that "target" is for "es5" and "lib" is "2016"

Answer (score 5):

Facing the same issue with Angular 6. Just only uncommenting Pollyfills doesn't work at all.
In addition to it add the meta tag  ***`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >`***  to your index.html file.

Comment: Once, I add this meta tag to my index (after adding the pollyfills), it started working in IE.
Check whether you use animations in your app. Incase, you do so, you may have to add classlist and web-animations to your pollyfills.

Comment: Hey, I had an issue where locally, it was working well but when i build and deployed, the application couldn't load in IE11 but the meta tag saved me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First open the file in your IDE or text editor: ie-test\src\polyfills.ts
Un-comment all the import lines in there. Or just to replace all
// import 
with 
import

install 2 packages 
npm install --save classlist.js
npm install --save web-animations-js

now ng serve and check