# Internet Explorer says 'Invalid character in vendor.js' ( ` )

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular7

Angular 7 application not working on internet explorer. It says invalid character in vendor.js

I have already apply polyfills.ts changes but it still not working.

my tsconfig.json =>

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**solved**

I found a module 'identicons' which containing back-ticks and removed it from the project and the problem solved. Thank you all for your helps guys.

Comment: It could be because of the reason that IE may not be supporting some of the JS features used in code. Can you please check out the code at the given line and column in that file?

Comment: It's because you must have used ` template string (button below the Esc), IE 11 does not support it. You should have to use " or ' for your strings

Comment: it is about ` character. In vendor.js there are ` characters and ie not supports it I know but should not compiler convert them for ie support ? I have already follow pollyfills directions.

Comment: I don't think compilers converts it. Also for polyfills you can add this script in your index.html `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.min.js`

Comment: You could refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192843/angular-applications-throwing-syntax-errors-on-ie11-only/57193444#57193444) in another thread. And the polyfills are only for the popular used es6+ functions which are not in IE11. If your code contains more code that is not supported then you have to find the polyfill yourself.

Comment: None of these worked unfortunately. The problem is a third party library which includes back-ticks. I thought compiler take care of them but in my project it does not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like back-ticks are used at that line and IE11 doesn't support it.
To make it work you will have to transpile your code with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I think babel will solve the problem but I could not figure out how to transpile the outputs with babel during or after compile my angular project. Is there any way/documentation about this?

Comment: You can refer this [article](https://medium.com/@hubert.zub/using-babel-7-and-preset-typescript-to-compile-angular-6-app-448eb1880f2c).

Comment: TS target is set to ES5, so it is transpiled correctly.

Comment: it was "identicons" module!! just removed it from the project and error gone. Thank you all. I am updating my question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you must have used ` template string (button below the Esc), IE 11 does not support it. You should have to use " or ' for your strings

More info

https://caniuse.com/#search=string

Comment: TS target is set to ES5, so it is transpiled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have as target `es5` for your typescript, so there is nothing wrong inside your own source code, because it will transpile to normal quotes.

Also the errors comes from `vendor.js`. This means that you are using a custom library which does not support IE11. Probably browsing the vendor.js where the error resides will give you a clue which library is causing it