# Angular application is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, angular

I have uncommented all the required import from pollyfill.js and install classlist.js and web-animations.js, then also in IE not working and coming only blank page.

Please help me and suggest what I need to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using angular 5

Comment: whats the error in console?

Comment: There is no error in cansole. @PratapA.K

Comment: Hi All,
Please help me on this because I am totally stuck because of this,Even I am not getting any error in console also

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue is posted in the following link:

> [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

Try to go through the answers in this post. It may help you out.
Also, stop and restart the server after uncommenting all the required code from the `polyfill.ts`.

Comment: I have tried with all the solution given in that post but nothing is working...Please help me what I need to do. Even I am not getting any error also in IE11.