# Angular 2 application not working in IE, MAC Safari

Tags: javascript, angular

When I am opening my application in IE, Mac Safari the login page is not open and I am getting error in console : 
SCRIPT5009: '_' is undefined
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

Answer (score 1):

search polyfill.ts file in our project and uncomment the polyfills

---

Are you using lodash/underscore package in your project? If yes then you need to install it

Comment: Please don't forget to install classlist.js `npm install --save classlist.js`, if you uncommented that also. You may need this later in your project as you progress

Comment: can you please share this file

Comment: Currently this line "import 'classlist.js'" is commented in my ts file do I need to open or Uncomment this ?

Comment: @ShailendraTiwari  `'_' is undefined` generally means that you are using lodash or underscore lib

Comment: and you are not importing this

Answer (score 0):

In polyfill.ts you need to uncomment below code.

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: Can you post your polyfill.ts file in your question?

Comment: I applied all those options those you all mentioned in comment but not works for me.