# Angulr6 application not running in IE and Edge

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, browser, microsoft-edge

I have one SPA devel0ped in Angular6, it works fine in chrome and Firefox but i get blank screen in IE and Edge.I have un-commented all the imports in polyfill.js for IE and Edge still i can't see my application running in IE n Chrome both.

Comment: And nothing in the console.log? (Welcome to Stackoverflow by the way)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: You are probably forgetting to target `es5` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools to debug your code and check whether it contains some error.