# After deploying an Angular 6 Application in IIS I'm getting a blank page with no error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, iis

I've deploy an Angular 6 Application with asp.net mvc in IIS and i"m getting a blank page.

it's only present the title inside the `<head>` in the html but not all contents -   angular 6 components inside.

i build the dist folder:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /ePortal/
```

with web.config:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="/*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/ePortal" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

then i have created an application in IIS

Please advice.

Comment: Did you look at the [Event Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer)?

Comment: did you install [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)  on server.

Comment: @JoelJoseph Yes i installed  IIS URL Rewrite on the server

Comment: @JoelJoseph you get an internal server error if its not installed vs blank page, I am having this issue rn.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found that keeping `<base href="">` as empty worked, whenever I refresh the page, there is no longer a 404 error showing up. I'm not sure why this is the case however, I'll keep researching on this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added base-href in html header?

```
<html>
   <head>
     ...
     <base href="/ePortal/">
     ...
   </head>
</html>
```

Have you deployed the dist folder package as, 'ePortal' at IIS Server?

From the example, it looks like you also referred [KudVenkat's Deploy angular app to IIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkGmaVm6-IQ) :)

**UPDATE:**
For IE 10 & IE 11 browsers, you need to uncomment a few lines in Polyfills.ts to import a few libraries. You refer to @Belen Martin's answer from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11). It worked for me. I always thought IE won't support Angular website. Thanks for this question!

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i did... i followed this tutorial but all i"m getting is a blank page .. it's getting the index.html page because i see the title in the browser but the content is not showing

Comment: Why do we need URL Rewrite here?

Comment: @Livnat Menashe, vote if this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

On the server wasn't installed chrome so i checked it with explorer and didn't work.. after i installed chrome - the page load good - so the problem solved (at least on chrome)