# TypeError: Object doesn't support this action (node_modules)

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I already checked all the similar issues with regards to this error in stackoverflow. However, my issue rather seems unique as the error is not due to my own code on the script itself. Rather to Angulars modules that are imported alright (the scripts included in the node_modules directory). When I'm debugging the code, all of the errors points out to  every node_modules scripts, and mostly pointing over and over again back to a specific file named _object-sap.js. I only encounter this issue in IE, and I've already uncommented the polyfill files and even added some more shims, still the issue exist. it's just some code I could not edit actually as this modules/libraries are maintained and imported with angular. How do I fix this?, Are there any specific polyfills that I need to import for this to work in I.E?. Because this seems to be rather dependency/polyfill issues to me but I could no longer get where would I get those and if ever I did wrong on importing dependencies or polyfills.

THe following screenshots are some of the things happening on debug.

---

Console output:
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I already converted the es6 polyfill files to es5 with a transpiler (as could be seen in the screenshot), and still the issue exist. (so I just reverted this changes back to the default polyfill files included in the polyfil.ts file.

### [image]

---

Also, when I was searching for the error Object.free: argument is not an Object which is one of the errors being thrown.
[Object.freeze Error Fix](https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax/issues/21)
It seems that I just need to pass an argument as it is required on IE. But this is a module in Angular, I don't have to edit this afaik among other node_modules files.

How do I fix this 13 errors then?. TIA

Comment: Try to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> in your index.html file. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11 and https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9

Comment: I already did that before, although I did it again when you said so. The error on files it points to just change. But basically still the same errors are being thrown by I.E :/

Comment: Did you also installed the NPM packages that mentioned in the second link which I suggested you in my previous comment?