# Angular 5 : Autosugesstion - Working fine in chrome, having issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, angular, angular5, datalist, autosuggest

I am using Angular 5, and i have used following code to implement autosuggestion feature, getting the suggestion values from an API

HTML Code :

```
    <div class="col col-lg-4">
          <label for="insuranceCompanyName"> Insurance Company Name </label>
          <input appDisablePaste list="companyLists" class="form-control input-sm" name="insuranceCompanyName" id='insuranceCompanyName'
          formControlName="insuranceCompanyName"/>
          <datalist id="companyLists" (scroll)="10" maxlength="20">
            <select>
              <option *ngFor="let companyOption of companyListOptions" [ngValue]="companyOption.rid">{{companyOption.companyName}}</option>
            </select>
          </datalist>
        </div>
```

TS code :

```
    onAutoSuggestion() {
    this.bpForm.controls['insuranceCompanyName'].valueChanges
    .debounceTime(600)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(queryField => queryField.length >= 3 && this.searchSvc.search(queryField)
    .subscribe((lookupResults: InsuranceCompany[]) =>
           this.companyListOptions = lookupResults, err => console.log(err)));
  }
```

In Chrome, it works completely fine. As soon as I type, i get the dropdown, with all the expected values.
In Internet explorer, I don't get the results unless I click on the text-field. The API has given the response, but the dropdown doesn't appear unless I click. 
Also, it does not show all the result values. Only few of it (checked in the API response in the developer console, response has much more records, but only a few of them are seen in the dropdown).

Edit :
The DOM explorer shows 24 entries in the loaded HTML
Screenshot - 
[html_dom_explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3866.png)

Here's the screen, with just 2 entries shown.
Screenshot - [dropdown_on_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtkUs.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem because of Angular ES6 code cant work on the IE browser and Angular on IE   11, 10, 9 ("compatibility view" mode not supported) so you need to translate your es6 code to es5 js code for the run on the IE browser.  More details you can find on this link

[Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)