# Angular 2 application does not works properly in Internet explore, but works well with other browsers

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

My angular application works fine with all web browsers except internet explorer. It shows this error in console.

[image]

polypills.ts looks like this,

```
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/array';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
```

Comment: you can refer below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11

Answer (score 0):

since the answers from [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

didn't work with me, I found the issue was not with the polyfills. Error has come from the new java-script function which used syntax's not supported by IE. Only works with browsers like chrome. I change the syntax to older version and fixed the issue. Now works fine with IE too.

Comment: Those errors are showing in the IE console as syntax errors.