# IE11 and Angular Issue - ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, typeerror

The App runs on chrome edge firefox and not on ie11.
The error doesn't mention the action.. any idea on what action it is / might be ?
Attaching a screenshot of the error and the polyfill.ts.

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es7/array';

import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.


(window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.

if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches = (Element.prototype as any).msMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;
}

import 'intl'; // Run `npm install --save intl`.

import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

[image]

Comment: You'll want to examine the stack in the error and find out what line and character position it is complaining about.

Comment: You did not mention which Angular version you are using for developing your project? Does an empty project is also not running with the IE browser? Did you try to add "target": "es5" to tsconfig.json file? If not you can have a try. You can try to refer to suggestions in this thread and article.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11 and https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT its angular 8, and yeah I have the target: es5 in my tsconfig.

Comment: Please inform us, whether new empty Angular project is working with Ie 11 or not? You can try to create and check it. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT no the new empty app doenst work on ie 11

Comment: It can be the issue with the configuration in your app. I suggest you refer the steps in this link. https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920 Try to add tsconfig-es5.app.json. modify the angular.json. Try to run the app. On my side app is working fine with Ie 11. https://imgur.com/a/3nBj76W

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT it was an issue with the way I was creating objects, for eg 
new ClassA(
new ClassB(dataB), 
new ClassC(dataC)
).
I changed it to new ClassA({dataB, dataC}), and then changed the constructor accordingly.
Turns out it solved the issue. 
Something like a Factory Design Pattern, I feel kinda stupid about it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding