# Angular Form not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I have developed an Angular 6 Project. All is working well in Chrome, Mozilla and Apple browsers, but it is not working in Internet Explorer 11. I am unable to save the data on clicking button.

In the console(Network), when clicking the button, it's not calling the API.

Do I need any special import in angular TS file for IE11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 / 4 / 5 not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140718/angular-2-4-5-not-working-in-ie11)

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Try to set debugger in the button click event, whether the function is called? Besides, Can you post enough code or create a [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/) to reproduce the problem? It might be easier for us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Please add a [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `polyfills.ts` file and find the import statements commented out under the section `/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. */`:

```
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
```

Uncomment the above import to have your app working with those IE browsers but don't forget to run the following command.

```
npm install --save classlist.js
```

You might be also required to uncomment the following import:

```
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

And not to forget to run the following command:

```
npm install --save web-animations-js
```

**EDIT**

In `browserslist` file, you may replace `not IE 9-11` with `IE 9-11`.

Also, in `tsconfig.json` file, you may replace `"target": "es2015"` (or whatever) with `"target": "es5"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it won't working

Comment: Ok, Can you check the edit portion of my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain enough information to give an actual answer. However, IE11 + form gave me some trouble in the past.

In my case I had to add `type='submit'` to the submit button and `type='button'` to all other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

On the angular website it is clear written that does not support internet explorer 11 you will have to configure your angular project by using following steps written in readme file of this github page.

https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist