# WPF browser control - Call javascript function from C# using IE11 compatiblity

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am working on `WPF` application. I wanted run application in `IE11` mode so I used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

I made required `css` and `JavaScript` changes so everything works fine except

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop" + this.ClientID, "jsFunction('parameter1','parameter2');", true);
```

I have this line in `User Control`. When I called this code, `jsFunction` doesn't get called.

I tried to call alert to test but it doesn't work as well.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop" + this.ClientID, "alert('test')", true);
```

If I run this using web browsers like Google Chrome/IE9/IE10/IE11 it works fine. It doesn't work in `WPF web browser`.

If I change to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

then it works fine but I can't go back because my other changes might break.

PS.

I can't [modify machine keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx) because it is used by many users and we can't configure their computers.

Please suggest solution/alternative.

Comment: Perhaps you can modify `HKCU` keys? See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333982/1768303) helps.

Answer (score 0):

IE=11 is not a valid value, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx

Try using "IE=Edge" for IE11 support, as seen here: [Why use X-UA-Compatible IE=Edge anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346917/why-use-x-ua-compatible-ie-edge-anymore)

Comment: tried `"IE=edge` instead of `"IE=Edge` as mention in second link. No luck :(