# XPages : Outputed html tag in IE11

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I developed XPages application. When loading the page on IE, the outputed html tag is the following.

When loading the page with FQDN or IP Address of the host part,

```
<HTML lang=en>
```

When loading the page with the host name(this is defined in hosts file) of the host part,

```
<html class=" lotusui_ie lotusui_ie7" lang="en">
```

As a result, the layout is broken in the latter case. I'd like to expect the former tag is outputed in any cases.

Then, I used http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" but does not work. What causes this issue?

Comment: IE could emulate for IE7 when displaying pages from local domain. Add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to render it without emulation. You can also use F12 (developer tools) to set current document mode. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44529397/1181067

Comment: As I wrote, I used "X-UA-Compatible". Then the mode is changed but the html tag is still different as I wrote the above.

Comment: You mean, Xpages theming is just adding some style classes to the html tag? I do not understand the problem then?

Comment: I tested a simple XPages which just show 'test' string. The IE mode is changed by X-UA-Compatible but the html tag contains class=" lotusui_ie lotusui_ie7". As a result, the layout is not rendered as I expect. Then if I remove the class by F12 dev tool, the layout is my expectation. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, the "lotusui_ie lotusui_ie7" classes are set by the theming code (Dojo). This is probably because IE is rendering in compatibility mode. Check this out: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/internet-explorer-compatibility-view-mode-causes-lmi-issues-qradar-network-security-sensors

Comment: Thanks, I understand I need to remove the class after the pageload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How we set X-UA-Compatible:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
try {
    var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=10");
} catch (e) {
  dprint("IE emulation: " + e);
}}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks but I used the same code.

This code works for IE document mode, however the outputted HTML tag of XPage is  

<html class=" lotusui_ie lotusui_ie7" lang="en">

As a result, I can't get the layout I set by "X-UA-Compatible".

Comment: https://xomino.com/2015/09/30/oneui-ie7-seriously-another-one-of-those-days/#comments

Comment: document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("lotusui_ie7")

Comment: Thanks for useful information! I need to remove both classes. Removing only "lotusui_ie7" does not solve the layout issue.

Comment: document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("lotusui_ie", "lotusui_ie7")